# A least principle action and human behaviour

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differential-equations

Does anyone have an idea how the authors of this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-81722-6#additional-information
solved the equation 10? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi! It's preferred on this site that questions be self-contained, i.e. it woud be great if you could provide some more context/quote the relevant parts of the linked paper. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. The relevant part of the linked paper was equation 10 in it. I was reading about possible applications of the principle of least action in human behaviour and stumbled on this paper and then I found that equation difficult to solve.

Comment: This question is about solving a differential question, which makes it a question about math, not physics. It belongs on Math SE. And the equation should have been explicitly stated.

Comment: My apologies. I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

An equation of the form
$$\frac{d x}{d t} = \sqrt{x(1-x)}$$

can be solved by separation of variables
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} = \int dt$$

and the integral on the left-hand side can be evaluated with a change of variable. A possible change of variable that could be useful is derived recalling that the equation $y = \sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is the upper part of a circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered in $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$: it's useful to introduce the "angular" variable $\theta$ so that the circle is described as
$$ x(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos\theta \qquad y(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\sin\theta \ ,$$
so that the differential reads $dx = -\frac{1}{2} \sin \theta \, d\theta$ and the integral becomes
$$\int d \theta \ .$$

This should solve your doubts. I leave you as an exercise the choice of the extremes of integration and the algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation (although I still don't the solution given on the paper).